# GCP key visualiser alerting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-monitoring

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the metrics monitored within the key visualiser for a spanner instance to automatically alert via email for a spanner instance? I can't seem to find if it's possible from the documentation.

If I go to create a monitoring policy, none of the metrics are the ones monitored within the key visualiser.

Read the documentation and had a look at the policies but couldn't see much that says its possible.